My call to glm in a function does not find the formula in the environment
In the following example, I create a function to fit a glm, but the function cannot find the formula defined immediately before. I believe this has to do with the function looking in the wrong environment, but I can't understand why. Here is an example:
n <- 20
ncov <- 3
df <- as.data.frame(replicate(ncov+1, runif(n)))
names(df) <- c(paste0("x", seq(ncov)), "y")
df

fun1 <- function(mod, pTrain = 0.5){
  print(environment())
  data <- mod$data
  y <- mod$y
  train <- sample(nrow(data), size = nrow(data)*pTrain)
  valid <- -train
  modTrain <- update(object = mod, data = data[train,])
  yhat <- predict(modTrain, newdata = data[valid,])
  res <- data.frame(y = y, yhat = yhat)
  return(res)
}

fun2 <- function(useCovs = c(1,0,0), data = df){
  print(environment())
  fmla <- formula(paste("y ~", paste(paste0("x", seq(useCovs))[as.logical(useCovs)], collapse = " + ")))
  # environment(fmla) <- environment() # does not help
  mod <- glm(formula = fmla, data = data)
  res <- fun1(mod, pTrain = 0.5)
  score <- sqrt(mean((res$y - res$yhat)^2))
  return(c(aic = AIC(mod), rmse = score))
}

fmla <- NULL # just to be sure there is no
fun2(useCovs = c(1,0,1))
# Error in eval(mf, parent.frame()) : object 'fmla' not found

If I use a <<- assignment for the formula, the function works, but I worry about the potential issues with this:
fun3 <- function(useCovs = c(1,0,0), data = df){
  print(environment())
  fmla <<- formula(paste("y ~", paste(paste0("x", seq(useCovs))[as.logical(useCovs)], collapse = " + ")))
  mod <- glm(formula = fmla, data = data)
  res <- fun1(mod, pTrain = 0.5)
  score <- sqrt(mean((res$y - res$yhat)^2))
  return(c(aic = AIC(mod), rmse = score))
}

fmla <- NULL # just to be sure there is no
fun3(useCovs = c(1,0,1)) # works
fmla # this equals the environment of fun2


I don’t think formula takes a text argument. If you want to build a formula then as.formula is the standard approach. Voting to close as a typo.

Hmmm.  It also works if you pass fmla as an argument to fun1...

Inspired by this post - in particular, the answer that has not been accepted - this seems to solve the problem.
fun1 <- function(mod, pTrain = 0.5){
  data <- mod$data
  y <- mod$y
  train <- sample(nrow(data), size = nrow(data)*pTrain)
  valid <- -train
  # New code
  ev <- environment()
  parent.env(ev) <- environment(mod$formula)
  environment(mod$formula) <- ev
  # End of new code
  modTrain <- update(object = mod, data = data[train,])
  yhat <- predict(modTrain, newdata = data[valid,])
  res <- data.frame(y = y, yhat = yhat)
  return(res)
}

I cannot explain why, though the discussion in the accepted answer above is probably worth some study.
As I mentioned in my comment, amending the signature of fun1 to
fun1 <- function(mod, pTrain = 0.5, fmla)

and the call to it in fun2 to
  res <- fun1(mod, pTrain = 0.5, fmla)


also succeeds.

I had not thought that the issue was in fun1, but you are right. It does fit in fun2, and fails during the update in fun1

Another option for fun1 would be to adjust the call to  update: fmla <- mod$formula; modTrain <- update(object = mod, data = data[train,], formula = as.formula(fmla, env = environment()))

Replace
mod <- glm(formula = fmla, data = data)

with
mod <- do.call("glm", list(formula = fmla, data = data))

or alternately with (less preferred)
mod <- eval(substitute(glm(fmla, data = data), list(fmla = fmla)))

so that the value of fmla is passed to glm rather than the fmla variable.  Normally this would not matter but glm uses non-standard evaluation (NSE) so it does.
